# SQL CE Compact 3.5 Identity columns for a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, identity-column

Is there a query I can write against an INFORMATION_SCHEMA or against the system tables to determine if a column is an identity column in SQL CE version 3.5?

Comment: Here is the web link to the answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/f0a5b6ef-9375-4af2-9a17-34db3ca700bd?prof=required&lc=1033

Answer (score 0):

Use **COLUMNPROPERTY** . For ur reference

a) 
[COLUMNPROPERTY (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174968.aspx)

b) 
[Identity Columns](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/identity-columns/)

Comment: COLUMNPROPERTY function is not available in SQL CE Compact 3.5. Here is the link for your reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
;WITH PK_INFO AS (SELECT CON.TABLE_CATALOG, CON.TABLE_SCHEMA, CON.CONSTRAINT_NAME, USO.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS CON
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE USO ON CON.CONSTRAINT_NAME = USO.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        AND CON.TABLE_CATALOG = USO.TABLE_CATALOG AND CON.TABLE_SCHEMA = USO.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE CON.TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE'
    AND CON.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    ) SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN (PK.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS COLUMN_IS_PRIMARYKEY, * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS COL 
LEFT JOIN PK_INFO PK on COL.COLUMN_NAME = PK.COLUMN_NAME WHERE COL.TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE' ORDER BY COL.ORDINAL_POSITION ASC
```